# get the second element with mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

when i execute the code  bellow i get this on output

> Suits FRENCH
>
> Suits ITALIEN

but i need the second element the link , how can i get it ? 
i dont understand something when i execute only a.get("http://............links_with(:href => %r{/suits-}) everything is good

```
 0.upto(5) do |f|
   p = a.get("http://www.xxxx/recherche/#{name}/page-#{f}").links_with(:href => %r{/suits-})
   puts p
end
```

> Mechanize::Page::Link "Suits FRENCH " "http://www.xxxxxx/rent/r-s-t/suits-french.html"> ,
>
> Mechanize::Page::Link "Suits ITALIEN" "http://www.xxxxx/rent/r-s-t/suits-italien.html">*

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
links = a.get("http://www.xxxx/recherche/#{name}/page-#{f}").links_with(:href => %r{/suits-})
link = links[1]
```

0 being the first, and 1 being the second.